# Does adding this root match template interfere with existing transformations?

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

Say you have an XSLT which is currently in use for a myriad of cases. Given that it does not currently have any `<xsl:template match="/">`; would adding the following template interfere with anything?

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="some condition which is only true for new cases"></xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Reason I'm asking is that we have a huge XSLT file which is currently in use and should not be broken, but we need to add some new transformations to it. Making some decisions on the root would make things a lot easier and cleaner.

I was just told that if there is no template matching `/`, then a default template equivalent to `<xsl:apply-templates />` will be applied. So, just wanting to check if my understand is correct, and that this then (as long as the test is only true for new cases) would not break any existing transformations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct, you can handle your conditions within the root template "/" and just apply-templates for the "normal" treatement.

But check existing root templates matching "/" - maybe it is already doing more than just apply the next templates.

Comment: There's always one? When I search for `match="/"` I find nothing. Doesn't that mean there isn't one?

Comment: You can have XSLT without template that match document root.But searching for `match="/"` is not 100% sure to check there is one.

Comment: Aha. What would a root template not matching on / look like?

Comment: Root template means matching "/" - matching the root element. Otherwise it is not really a root template.